# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I was trying out a sample springboot project. But in the half way i got stuck up with this problem.

My Controller.java

```
package org.springbootdemo5.springbootdemo5.controler;
import org.springboot5.springbootdemo5.service.TaskService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class SampleRestController {
    @Autowired
private TaskService taskService;
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String hello(){
    return "Hello World!!!";
}}
```

My Task Service

```
package org.springboot5.springbootdemo5.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springboot5.springbootdemo5.dao.TaskRepository;
import org.springboot5.springbootdemo5.model.Task;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Transactional
public class TaskService {

private final TaskRepository taskRepository;

public TaskService(TaskRepository taskRepository) {
    this.taskRepository = taskRepository;
}

public List<Task> findAll(){
    List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Task task : taskRepository.findAll()){
        tasks.add(task);
    }
    return tasks;
}
public Task findTask(int id){
    return taskRepository.findOne(id);
}

public void save(Task task){
    taskRepository.save(task);
}
public void delete(int id){
    taskRepository.delete(id);
}}
```

My Task Repository

```
package org.springboot5.springbootdemo5.dao;

import org.springboot5.springbootdemo5.model.Task;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
public abstract class TaskRepository implements CrudRepository<Task, Integer>
{
}
```

And this my Initializer

```
package org.springbootdemo5.springbootdemo5;

 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("org.springboot5.springbootdemo5")
public class Springbootdemo5Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Springbootdemo5Application.class, args);
}}
```

All the annotations are provided properly and pom.xml is also correct but still i am getting exception like

```
Exception 
encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
creating bean with name 'taskService' defined in file 
  Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No 
qualifying bean of type 'org.springboot5.springbootdemo5.dao.TaskRepository' 
available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
Dependency annotations: {}

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in 
org.springboot5.springbootdemo5.service.TaskService required a bean of type 
'org.springboot5.springbootdemo5.dao.TaskRepository' that could not be 
found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 
'org.springboot5.springbootdemo5.dao.TaskRepository' in your configuration.
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springbootdemo5</groupId>
<artifactId>springbootdemo5</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>springbootdemo5</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
<artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>9.0.0.M26</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Anybody can solve this ?
Any help is always welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: Your packages seams to be mixed `org.springbootdemo5.springbootdemo5` versus `org.springboot5.springbootdemo5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `TaskRepository`

to

`public interface TaskRepository extends CrudRepository<Task, Integer>`

Comment: Thank you sir but i tried already and the  same problem persists.

Comment: I'd remove the `ComponentScan` too. It's not required. The SpringBootApplication annotation will trigger a component scan from it's package. What does your POM look like?

Comment: I have added my pom.xml and if i remove     ComponentScan its throwing one more exceptopn like:-  Field taskService in org.springbootdemo5.springbootdemo5.controler.MainController required a bean of type 'org.springboot5.springbootdemo5.service.TaskService' that could not be found.

Comment: have you verified that you've built against the latest code?  Looking at the code and POM it should run fine. `mvn clean install`

Comment: I downloaded the new package from spring.io then i started coding. According to me also it should work fine but u don't why it's sick up like this. .Any other modifications suggested..? When I am running as maven install it's saying compilation failure.

Comment: Package names are different across the packages. Should be uniform e.g `org.springbootdemo5.springbootdemo5` vs org.springboot5.springbootdemo5` this is why some beans are being scanned and not others. And why removing the `ComponentScan` caused a different error.

Comment: I hope package name only was creating a problem.its solved now.tgank you a lot sir.

Answer (score 0):

Check the bean ID mentioned in the xml and the member in the Java file should be same , which is case sensitive.

### config.xml

```
<bean id="reportServicePdf" class="my.local.spring.sprintlex.ReportService">
        <constructor-arg name="numberOfPage" value="11" /> //<====Here
    </bean>
```

### ReportService.java:

```
public class ReportService {    
@Value("100")
    private int numberOfPage;//<====Here

::
::
}
```